# Get Flutter/Vscode to use Java from newly installed Android Studio?

Tags: android, linux, flutter, android-studio, dart

I just installed **Android Studio 2022.2** in addition to the existing **Android Studio 2021.2** on my Ubuntu 22.04 system.

When I build my Flutter app through Vscode by running `Run > Start debugging`, the build will fail and the error messages show that it is still using the bundled JDK of the old Andriod Studio `/opt/android-studio-2021.2.1/android-studio/jre`

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
      Your current JDK is located in /opt/android-studio-2021.2.1/android-studio/jre
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

This is the output of `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 5.19.0-41-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.10.4 on channel stable at /home/gameveloster/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 682aa387cf (3 days ago), 2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
    • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb
    • Dart version 3.0.3
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/gameveloster/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio-2022.2.1.20-linux/android-studio/jbr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio-2022.2.1.20-linux/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio-2021.2.1/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] VS Code
    • VS Code at /snap/code/current
    • Flutter extension version 3.66.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop)   • linux              • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 5.19.0-41-generic
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome             • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.106

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

In `/opt` I have

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   47 Jun  8 13:26  android-studio -> android-studio-2022.2.1.20-linux/android-studio/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   38 Aug  3  2022  android-studio-2021 -> android-studio-2021.2.1/android-studio/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 13  2022  android-studio-2021.2.1/
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun  8 13:15  android-studio-2022.2.1.20-linux/
```

There's no java or flutter paths in my `$PATH`.

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/gameveloster/go/bin:/home/gameveloster/.go/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/gameveloster/.cargo/bin:/home/gameveloster/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/gameveloster/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the `/opt/android-studio-2022.2.1.20-linux/android-studio/jbr`?

Comment: @plplmax I want to try this. How do I set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable so that Vscode can use it when I build the app via `Run > Start Debug` or pressing the F5 key?

Comment: Try to add `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk` in `~/.bashrc` and reopen VS code just in case